# Not detecting NVIDIA,but detect llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

At first, I could not install NVIDIA drivers 'cause a firmware problem. After I fixed this, I installed NVIDIA drivers from command line but when I reboot, instead of NVIDIA, was shown at "about this computer" llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits).

I tried everything, please help, I don't want to format again.

[image: screenshot showing system details]

```
alex@alex:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1193
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1193
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: The driver looks to be installed. Is secure boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: No, i couldnt disabled it

Comment: Please stop spoiling text formatting. I fixed it twice for you already. The driver won't work with Secure Boot enabled. Why you couldn't? How did you try?

Comment: I did and it works!!Thanks man you are life saver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot in UEFI aka BIOS and the driver should load properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in OpenSUSE Tumbleed (64-bit) when I updated my distro and installed the latest NVIDIA driver by using the `.run` script.

The issue was that all native 32-bit games used this renderer:

```
GL_RENDERER: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
```

and they ran much more slow, between 5 and 15 fps max.

That was because the software renderer was the only one detected and was used in case no other accelerated renderer is presented in the system. That was my case.

It turns out that the drivers were installed in:

```
/usr/lib32 instead of /usr/lib
```

(a standard path in my distribution).

The Mesa soft renderer (32-bit) was in:

```
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0
```

and NVIDIA 32-bit libraries were in:

```
/usr/lib32/libGLX_nvidia.so.465.31
```

The workaround was to export the library path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32"; doom3
```

`doom3` was the 32-bit game I tested in this case and works now with NVIDIA accelerated libraries.

To make it system-wide and for all users, I added this file:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/32bitlibs.conf
```

with the following line:

```
/usr/lib32
```

Then I ran:

```
ldconfig
```

and all  32-bit apps are now using the NVIDIA drivers.

---

In the case of Ubuntu, the system libraries for 32-bit are in:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

and for 64-bit:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

`/lib/i386-linux-gnu` is also used for 32-bit libraries.

I hope that this helps any other Linux user with a similar issue.