# I seem to be having both an external GPU (Nvidia) and an internal (llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits) in use at the same time, what do I do here?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

At startup I get a bunch of textcode (200~ lines of code with some mention of Nvidia here and there) after that Ubuntu starts.

When in Ubuntu at times I get a black screen for few seconds such as, when clicking Settings... Also I have had my resolution change automatically in similar times from a larger (native in monitor) to a smaller (user set resolution) by simply opening the Settings etc.

It seems I have in some ways managed to install the Nvidia 525 drivers for Geforce 2070 Super as I have previously also done but these time I can't get it to show up on "Settings->About"

Showing some contradicting info about GPU drivers:

[image]

It's like the drivers/the GPU isn't actually in use... what do I do here?

edit: Another thread ([Not detecting NVIDIA,but detect llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241103/not-detecting-nvidia-but-detect-llvmpipe-llvm-6-0-256-bits#comment2091121_1241103)) mentioned disabling Secure Boot from BIOS would solve the issue but is this safe? I have gotten Nvidia Geforce 2070 super and the same driver files to work previously fine on Ubuntu 20.04 without resorting in to this?

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Sat Apr 15 23:54:09 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8     8W / 215W |     14MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


johhnyboiii@john-Ubuntu-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Ubuntu-drivers or Software & Updates/Additional Drivers tab are the only two ways to install the Nvidia drivers which then get updated automatically and ask you for a signing key (so secure boot enabled will not prevent them from working). Clean out what you did and reinstall using one of the above.

Comment: It looks like you may have installed the NVIDIA drivers using a .run file, which could possibly cause this. Not sure how to uninstall those, but if there is a way to, I'd uninstall them and then try installing the drivers through the Software and Updates screen. Also, back up your data so that if anything goes wrong you can reinstall and restore your data.